# Angular momentum $L$ cannot be completely aligned with $z$-axis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

In reading a postulate on angular-momentum coupling, the author made this statement:

> In Q.M, the angular momentum cannot be complete aligned with the $z$-axis, otherwise its $x$ and $y$-components would be zero and be known simultaneously.

I don't fully understand this statement. 
Is there a better way to gain insight into this statement?

Comment: Related:  http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/189799/5739  Also, it seems to me that the author of that quote is mixing classical and quantum concepts.

Comment: @garyp as is often the case.  At least the OP had the wisdom of questioning the statement, and deserves kudos for it.

Comment: @garyp I agree with ZeroTheHero for I see nothing wrong with having to answer similar but intelligent questions from beginners; they are *beginners* and the subject is vast and complicated enough to get to he right question with the right answer, Google or other search engines notwithstanding.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Indeed!  I was too glib.  The intention was to point out that the statement in the quote is not well worded, and confusion about it is justified.  The answer in the duplicate question is better than anything I could have come up with.

Comment: @garyp I'm with you on this "classical" model of quantum angular momentum: it is often botched and such questions as the OP asked are rarely part of an informed discussion of this in classrooms.  By Jove! even professionals are sloppy with this as the "classical" model is so convenient and - if it's limitations are understood - a source of good insight.